# Leaflet Extra Markers Size

Tags: leaflet, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to use Leaflet ExtraMarkers (https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers) and control the size of the icon?  I have tried

```
var greenMarker = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
                    icon: 'fa-number',
                    iconSize: '[38,95]',
                    markerColor: 'green',
                    shape: 'circle',
                    prefix: 'fa',
                    number: "99" 
                })
```

with and without quotes on the iconSize to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

If Leaflet.ExtraMarkers doesn't fit your exact needs, maybe you should consider using [L.Icon.Glyph](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Icon.Glyph) and provide your own marker image, with whatever size you need.

Leaflet.ExtraMarkers uses image sprites for the background marker image - which can make it more difficult to use custom ones.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately icons from Leaflet.ExtraMarkers plugin are [images](https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers/blob/master/dist/img/markers_default.png), so you cannot adjust their size through simple code.

The `iconSize` option refers to the allocated `div` size on the map (in particular for positioning, mouse interaction, etc.), but it does not change the visual appearance.

Now you could change those images to get bigger version (or scale them through CSS), but do not forget to adjust the [icon options](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon-options) for positioning as well (`iconAnchor`, `popupAnchor`, etc.).

Comment: While it's technically possible to adjust the size of a image sprite, Leaflet.ExtraMarkers doesn't implement that. See the `bgPos` and `bgSize` options in L.Icon.Glyph.

Answer (score 1):

So this question is 3 years old by now but i hope someone will be able to use this.
This bothered me too so i found a way to resize the icons using map events.
I added three event listeners one for `zoomend` another for `addlayer` and a third for `dragend`, each of them resize the icons to the size i wanted (which was smaller).
The `scale` part of the code determines the size of the icon while you need to adjust to location using `translateX` and `translateY`.
Hopefully someone else will find this useful:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(){
        var ExtraMarkers = document.getElementsByClassName("extra-marker");
        for(l=0; l< ExtraMarkers.length; l++){
        oldS = ExtraMarkers[l].style.transform
        newS = oldS + " scale(0.5) translateY(100%) translateX(50%)" 
        ExtraMarkers[l].style.transform = newS

            }
    })
map.on("layeradd", function(layer){
    if(layer.layer._icon && 
        layer.layer._icon.classList.contains("extra-marker")){
        oldS = layer.layer._icon.style.transform;
        newS = oldS + " scale(0.5) translateY(100%) translateX(50%)" ;
        layer.layer._icon.style.transform = newS
       }
    })
L.marker([lat, lng],
                    {draggable:true, icon: L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
    icon: 'fa-number',
    markerColor: 'green',
    shape: 'penta',
    number: '1',
    prefix: 'fa'
  })
})
.on("dragend",function(e){
                        oldS = e.target._icon.style.transform;
                        newS = oldS + " scale(0.5) translateY(100%) translateX(50%)" ;
                        e.target._icon.style.transform = newS
                    });
```

Should you want to try out other sizes you should adjust the `translateX` and `translateY` arguments.

Comment: Thank you for giving your time in showing us this work!  I hope it's usable with https://mappingforyou.eu/france  and inside it, https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/mfy-wfs.js whose icons are too big. I'll try some day